# Android development - Application switching problem - generating new random string upon button click

Tags: android, string, button, random, click

Android development question:
I have a Vector that stores Strings of "tips" to display to users.  I want to generate a random tip whenever the user clicks a button.  However, I want it to be a different tip from the last one displayed.  The method I've implemented below works perfectly fine for achieving the task until the application is switched.  Upon re-entry of the application, a random tip is still displayed each time a user clicks the button, but the method for ensuring the tip is different no longer works.  Any clues as to why?
Thanks!

```
public void but_healthTip_Click(View view)
{
    TextView tipHolder;     
    tipHolder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_tips);
    Random genHealthTip = new Random();
    Integer curTip = tips.lastIndexOf(tipHolder.getText());
    Integer randTip = genHealthTip.nextInt(tips.size());

    while(randTip==curTip){
        randTip = genHealthTip.nextInt(tips.size());
    }

    tipHolder.setText(tips.elementAt(randTip));

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "re-entry"? Is it when you press home button and then reload your app?

Comment: Yes.  Also, it's part of a TabbedView, and clicking on any of the other tabs then clicking back to that tab will make the same thing happen.

Comment: Where do you call this method?

Comment: The method is called when the user clicks a button.

Comment: You wrote that this method works fine, but it doesn't work when you click the button. So when does it work fine?

Comment: Actually, I said, "The method I've implemented below works perfectly fine for achieving the task until the application is switched."

Comment: So, it works fine when the user clicks the button, so long as the application has not been switched.  Even after it has been switched, the button generates a random tip.  However, it is now possible that the tip the button displays is the same one as the previous click.

Comment: And, to note, it doesn't happen on just the first click upon application re-entry.  It may happen on any click after that.

Comment: And, now I've figured out the issue.  Apparently, that method works fine.  The thing that isn't working is the way I'm adding to the tip vector.  I do that onCreate(), which I didn't realize seems to be called every time the application re-enters.  So, when the application has been re-entered, the size of my vector doubles.  I am not sure where I should populate this vector instead.

Comment: Well, problem solved.  I still add to the vector onCreate(), but I created a static boolean variable to detect if this is the first time onCreate() has been run.  I only add to the vector the first time onCreate() is called now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem solved. I still add to the vector onCreate(), but I created a static boolean variable to detect if this is the first time onCreate() has been run. I only add to the vector the first time onCreate() is called now.